# Rails: Object creation with has_many / belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are two models `Task` and `Project`. A `Project` has many 'Task's and a 'Task' belongs_to a `Project'.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end
```

A list of all `Task`s is displayed as a separate page for each `Project` and displays your `Task`s.

How to create the condition for the method `create`, so that the `Task` be able to be created as an independent object, and associated with the `Project`?

My knowledge was only enough to write two separate methods.

To create associated objects:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
  redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

To create a separate object:

```
def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.js {}
      format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

How to do it one method?

Comment: Checkout [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for).

Comment: On what conditions, you want to create as independent? , If there is no Project for the project_id passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass in the project_id to your second method. Then you can add

```
@task.project_id = params[:project_id]
```

or something like that. If tasks always belongs to projects you may want to model them as a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: His question is to create task, with/without Project on the same method.

Comment: I had a hard time getting the question but it seems the questioneer was happy with the answer at least!

Answer (score 0):

**Task Controller:**

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.all
  @task  = Task.new
end

def create
 @task = if params[:project_id]
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @project.tasks.build(task_params)
 else
   Task.new(task_params)
 end
 ...
```

**Project Model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks,
                      :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and in projects controller

```
private      
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, ....., taks_attributes: [:id, .....,:_destroy])
end
```